# How to dump stack trace for all processes in Linux?

Tags: linux, android, debugging

I am trying to track down a bug on an Android device that involves IPC between several native processes. At a given point in time I would like to dump native stack traces for all threads in some or all of the native processes and maybe even the kernel threads as well. How can I do that?

I have full root and ability to recompile the Linux kernel if needed.